# ajax error results in success function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was working toward a solution for this recent post: [Repeating a function using array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324918/repeating-a-function-using-array-of-values) and in doing so, I stitched together the following piece of code.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

 var name_list = ['mike','steve','sean','roger'];
 
 var successAction = function(name) {
  console.log(name);
 }
 
 name_list.forEach(function(name) {
  jQuery.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "https://www.google.com/", 
   dataType: 'html',
   success: successAction(name)
  });
 });
 
</script>
```

I run this and not surprisingly the following error message is returned:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.google.com/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

**My question is this** - If the ajax request results in four failures such as it appears, then why is the success function called four times and correspondingly logging each name in the array?

Comment: you are assigning the return value of `successAction(name)` to `success`  instead of assign the function itself without invoke it. The right way must be just `success: successAction`

Comment: right you are - thanks, @salc2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: successAction(name)
```

could be replaced with

```
xxx: successAction(name)
```

and it would still print out the 4 times. The correct syntax should be

```
success: function(name) { successAction(name); }
```

Comment: Or directly `success: successAction` ^^